# Clion: Don't put `/nologo` flag to build.make

Tags: build, cmake, clion, flags

Question about `MSVC Toolchain`.

After generation, `cmake` makes files - one of them named `build.make`. See `hello world` project screen below:
[image]
Is it possible to prevent appending by default the `/nologo` (for cl.exe, link.exe) key in `build.make` ?

Comment: @Rob But I believe that it will be LESS UNDERSTANDING without a picture.  Since the picture more lethally displays information in this case.

Comment: @ilw: Still, a **text** is preferred over the picture. E.g. highlighting of a phrase is easy achieved with *text-search* feature of a browser (`Ctrl+F`). However, the question shouldn't be closed: its text already contains **all needed information**, and the screenshot could simply be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

Check the value of `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` variable. If it does contain `/nologo` flag, remove it and reconfigure the cache.

Otherwise, add `/logo` flag to `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` variable.

also
`set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE CACHE BOOL nologo FORCE)`

Comment: Yes, it is. At least, in Visual Studio 2017 version of `link.exe`. Passing `/logo` after `/nologo` overrides the latter.